# cloning a repository with ssh url link github on visual studio code

Tags: dart

When I try to clone my repository with ssh key in my visual studio code, they keep on saying Github denied public key.

This is what I have tried:

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\flutter projects\Olivapp\flutter1-repo> git clone git@github.com:Teng-Olive/flutter1-repo.git
Cloning into 'flutter1-repo'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\flutter projects\Olivapp\flutter1-repo>
```

I wanted to see the repository that I created in my visual studio code.